# Compiling linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can someone guide me through the process of compiling the linux kernel ,

1. Say if I changed some files in `/usr/src/linux/` what do I have to compile?
2. When do I need to compile also the kernel modules (if you can list the directories/files that would be nice)
3. If I want to add a call to the system_call_table i.e entry number #240, and I wrote a .c , .h files for that entry where do I put them?

Steps for compiling the kernel are :

- `cd /usr/src/linux`
- `make bzImage`
- `make modules`
- `make modules_install`
- `cd arch/i386/boot`
- `cp bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-"linux version"`
- `cd /boot`
- `mkinitrd "the image".img "version ..."`
- `reboot`

The problematic steps are `make modules` and `make modules_install`.

Comment: Did you succeeded in compiling and running a vanilla unmodified kernel?

Comment: 1. {1,2} and {3} are two different questions IMHO. 2. In what way are those two steps problematic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This book is excellent and Greg Kroah-Hartman (well known kernel developer) was kind enough to share it for free http://www.kroah.com/lkn/

**EDIT:
Greg has sent me updated links while he fixes the site http://files.kroah.com/lkn/**

> "To quote me, the author of the book:
> If you want to know how to
>   build, configure, and install a custom Linux kernel on your machine,
>   buy this book. It is written by someone who spends every day building,
>   configuring, and installing custom kernels as part of the development
>   process of this fun, collaborative project called Linux.
>
> I'm especially proud of the chapter on how to figure out how to
>   configure a custom kernel based on the hardware running on your
>   machine. This is an essential task for anyone wanting to wring out the
>   best possible speed and control of your hardware."

Comment: @minitech - please dont edit things that do not need editing - the format was fine and matched original site

Comment: I think the download links are down, right?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Um... it's a quote. It's not code. Does the format need to match?

Comment: @phimuemue They do appear to be - this is probably because of the intrusion to kernel.org earlier this year. I've emailed Greg to notify him

Comment: @minitech stop editing my answer. I want to put it in quotes because it is a quote.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Okay... I took it out of quotes because you took it out of quotes in your unquoting of my edit, so I figured that's how you wanted it.